# SoapException not caught in a ComVisible class

Tags: c#, interop, comvisible, soapexception

I am developing a ComVisible library in .NET which is then called in an old VB6 class. What I basically do in the class is calling a web service, parsing the response and returning an object with necessary data. The web service is designed so that it returns a `SoapException` if called with wrong parameter(s). Here is a part of my code:

```
    private static WCFPersonClient _client;
    private static ReplyObject _reply;

    public BFRWebServiceconnector()
    {
        _client = new WCFPersonClient("WSHttpBinding_IWCFPerson");
        _reply = new ReplyObject ();            
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public ReplyObject GetFromBFR(string bestallningsID, string personnr, bool reservNummer = false)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = new XmlDocument();

            //the service operation returns XML but the method in the generated service reference returns a string for some reason               
            var responseStr = _client.GetUserData(orderID, personnr, 3); reason.

            response.LoadXml(responseStr);
            //parse the response and fill the reply object
            .......
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _reply.Error = "Error: " + ex.Message;
            if (_client.InnerChannel.State == CommunicationState.Faulted) _client = new WCFPersonClient("WSHttpBinding_IWCFPerson"); //recreate the failed channel
        }
        return _reply;
    }
```

Once I try to call this method from my VB6 code with correct parameters, I get a proper reply. But if I call it with a wrong parameter, I get a `-245757` (`Object reference was not set to an instance of an object`) runtime error in my VB6 program and it seems that it's not caught by the `catch` clause in my C# code (while I would expect an empty `ReplyObject` with filled `Error` field returned by the method).

I have created a test C# project and copied the same method (i.e. I call the same web service from within the .NET platform) and I can confirm that in this case the `SoapException` is being properly caught.

Is this behavior intentional? Is there a way to catch the `SoapException` within a ComVisible class (since I really would like to include the error message into my reply object)?

UPD: My VB6 code is following:

```
Set BFRWSCReply = New ReplyObject
Set BFRWSC = New BFRWebbServiceconnector
Set BFRWSCReply = BFRWSC.GetFromBFR(m_BeställningsID, personnr)

If Not IsNull(BFRWSCReply) Then
    If BFRWSCReply.Error= "" Then
       m_sEfternamn = BFRWSCReply.Efternamn
       //etc i.e. copy fields from the ReplyObject
    Else
       MsgBox BFRWSCReply.Error, vbExclamation
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Maybe `_replay` object is not initialized while error is set in catch clause: `_reply.Error = "Error: " + ex.Message;`

Comment: @algirdas, no, it is initialized, in the constructor.

Comment: What is the runtime error from VB?

Comment: @DStanley it's `-245757 Error 1 - Application-defined or object-defined error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Is the `ReplyObject` marked as `ComVisible` as well?

Comment: @DStanley yes, it is `ComVisible` as well.

Comment: Returning global variables is asking for trouble.  Be sure to use the debugger, setting it up to allow debugging both VB6 and C# code is covered in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11975581/17034

Comment: @HansPassant unfortunately I cannot debug the program as the web service is only accessible from a test machine via VPN where I got no VisualStudio...

Comment: @Azimuth then my guess about scope is probably wrong since the _data_ for the class is marshaled, the service can do anything it wants with the objects.  Are you trying to access a specific property of the `ReplyObject` when the exception occurs?

Comment: @DStanley do you mean in the VB6 code? If so, yes, I check if the `Error` field is empty and if not I try to read other fields of the object. I updated the question with my VB6 code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm very ashamed that the reason was very very simple... Instead of following:

```
catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _reply.Error = "Error: " + ex.Message;
        if (_client.InnerChannel.State == CommunicationState.Faulted) _client = new WCFPersonClient("WSHttpBinding_IWCFPerson"); //recreate the failed channel
    }
```

I had actually following code:

```
catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _reply.Error = "Error: " + ex.Message + "; " + ex.InnerException.Message;
        if (_client.InnerChannel.State == CommunicationState.Faulted) _client = new WCFPersonClient("WSHttpBinding_IWCFPerson"); //recreate the failed channel
    }
```

and it turns out that `ex.InnerException` was `null` which caused the `NullPointerException`...

Answer (score 0):

(this is just a guess and is more fitting for a comment but it's pretty long)

It's possible that the .NET runtime is disposing of the `ReplyObject` COM object when the `BFRWebServiceconnector` class goes out of scope, maybe because it is a property of the class and not created within the method?

Try creating the `ReplyObject` within `GetFromBFR` instead of making it a property of the class.  That also might prevent weird errors from multithreaded access if the COM object is called from different threads.

Also if there's a particular line in the VB program that is throwing the error (after you call `GetFromBFR`), you could see if the variable is `Nothing` within VB to try and narrow down the problem.

Like I said, just a guess.  Feel free to refute it. :)

Comment: I will try to create the `ReplyObject` within the method. Somehow I missed this point myself...